# Run script when eth0 UP

Tags: bash, shell, networking

I need to run a script after the start **eth0** interface in Centos 6.8

When I do it with **ppp0** I put scripts here: `/etc/ppp/ip-up.local` and it works. 
How to do the same with **eth0**?

I tried to put scripts in difference files, checking permissions, but does not work.

Files that I tried to put scripts:

```
**/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ip-up.local
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-local
/sbin/ifup-pre-local
/sbin/ifup-local
/sbin/ip-up.local**
```

Comment: Check this. https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2011-September/117632.html It was working with older version of centos. I used it. But i am not sure whether it is working with current version or not.

Comment: I tried it but nothing comes out. maybe it's because I use Network Manager ... When I put script to /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d it work but repeated many times.

Comment: can you confirm you are checking against your interface and status as per this example https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Use_dispatcher_to_connect_to_a_VPN_after_a_network_connection_is_established

Comment: Thank you. It works just as I need.

Answer (score 3):

Using **NetworkManager**, we can create a file `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/15-my-ip-up-local` that will run the necessary scripts

```
#!/bin/bash
### /bin/bash /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/15-my-ip-up-local

if [ "$1" = "eth0" ] && [ "$2" = "up" ]; then
echo run my scripts in up
else
echo DO_NOTHING
fi
```

Comment: Do you need to restart the interface or something or it just works. And where does the `echo` output show up.