# My systemd unit file and bash scripts not working for interface ppp0 checks

Tags: bash, networking, systemd, ppp, l2tp

Trying to understand systemd and craft a service that works , using two bash scripts I have to down/up an IPsec/L2tpd tunnel. All works fine if I use the bash scripts commands from the command line, but for some reason I'm getting race conditions or lack of sync or something because using my systemd unit file is random and intermittent often requiring a random number of restarts to get it working.

## vpn-disconnect.sh

```
echo "d myvpn" > /var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control
ipsec down myvpn
while grep ppp0 /proc/net/dev < /dev/null; do
        echo "Waiting for ppp0 to go down ..."
        sleep 5
done
echo "$0: ppp0/myvpn now down"
```

## vpn-connect.sh

```
VPN_SERVER_IP='161.35.36.182'
VPN_IPSEC_PSK='Vsumz0402#tillykeats'
VPN_USER='pi'
VPN_PASSWORD='Psumz0402'

if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]] ; then
  echo "$0: Must be run as ROOT"
  exit 1
fi

/home/daz/VPN/vpn-disconnect.sh

echo "
### Creating ipsec connections file ..."
cat > /etc/ipsec.conf <<EOF
config setup

conn %default
  ikelifetime=60m
  keylife=20m
  rekeymargin=3m
  keyingtries=1
  keyexchange=ikev1
  authby=secret
  ike=aes128-sha1-modp2048!
  esp=aes128-sha1-modp2048!

conn myvpn
  keyexchange=ikev1
  left=%defaultroute
  auto=add
  authby=secret
  type=transport
  leftprotoport=17/1701
  rightprotoport=17/1701
  right=$VPN_SERVER_IP
EOF

echo "
### Creating PSK file ..."
cat > /etc/ipsec.secrets <<EOF
: PSK "$VPN_IPSEC_PSK"
EOF
chmod 600 /etc/ipsec.secrets

echo "
### Creating xl2tpd config file ..."
cat > /etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf <<EOF
[lac myvpn]
lns = $VPN_SERVER_IP
ppp debug = yes
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.l2tpd.client
length bit = yes
EOF

echo "
### Creating PPP client file ..."
cat > /etc/ppp/options.l2tpd.client <<EOF
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
refuse-eap
require-chap
noccp
noauth
mtu 1280
mru 1280
noipdefault
defaultroute
usepeerdns
connect-delay 5000
name $VPN_USER
password $VPN_PASSWORD
EOF
chmod 600 /etc/ppp/options.l2tpd.client

echo "
### Creating control file ..."
mkdir -p /var/run/xl2tpd
touch /var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control

echo "
### Restarting services ..."
service strongswan restart
service xl2tpd restart

echo "
### Bringing up connection ..."
ipsec up myvpn
echo "c myvpn" > /var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control
while ! grep ppp0 /proc/net/dev ; do
        echo "waiting for ppp0 ..."
        sleep 5
done

echo "
### DONE !!"
ifconfig
```

## /etc/systemd/system/vpn.service

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
#Type=forking
#Type=notify
#Type=simple
#User=root
#Restart=no
#RuntimeMaxSec=10
#RestartSec=1
#User=root
WorkingDirectory=/tmp
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/home/vpn-connect.sh'
#ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 10
#ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '/home/vpn-disconnect.sh'
#KillMode=process
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=inherit
#SuccessExitStatus=0 143
#RestartSec=5
#Restart=on-failure
#TimeoutStopSec=120
#LimitNOFILE=102642

[Unit]
Description=IPsec L2TP tunner
After=network-online.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The intention is to bring up ppp0 interface (or take it down) through the service. I've had several symptoms with this and as you can see I've tried various configurations (commenting them in/out). I'm lost. Various conditions I'm getting with this config:-

- race conditions where vpn-connect starts before vpn-disconnect finishes.
- zombie processes for the bash scripts which prevent the newly started ones from completing (conflict with each other trying to down/up ppp0)
- vpn-connect never ending because ppp0 isnt up.
- vpn-disconnect failing because ppp0 doesnt go down.
  and more - confused!

Like I say, it is all perfect if I run them from the command line as **. ./vpn-connect.sh** or **. ./vpn-disconnect.sh** as and when I need them, such as **vpn-connect** after I log in and **vpn-disconnect** before I power down.

help please :)

I accept I'm probably not doing this the 'correct' way but I'm no expert and have tried and got some way, before coming here. There is probably a better way of checking if the ppp0 interface is down/up and there's certainly got to be a better way of crafting the service file?

Thanks in advance Gurus.

Comment: Redirect the output to a log file to see whats going on.

Comment: `RemainAfterExit=yes` but.. when you stop the service, it will just stop immidately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two script! That will be hard to manage. Consider making one script and pass mode with arguments. But you can just use one script and auto-clean with a trap. Like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
# vpn-connect.sh
shutdown_func() {
    # the stuff from vpn-disconnect.sh here
    echo "d myvpn" > /var/run/xl2tpd/l2tp-control
    ipsec down myvpn
    while grep ppp0 /proc/net/dev < /dev/null; do
            echo "Waiting for ppp0 to go down ..."
            sleep 5
    done
    echo "$0: ppp0/myvpn now down"
}
# execute shutdown function when requested to... shutdown
trap 'shutdown_func' SIGTERM

# the rest of vpn-connect.sh script
: blablabl

echo "
### DONE !!"
ifconfig # ??
sleep infinity
```

then don't `RemainAfterExit=yes` and just only do:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash /home/vpn-connect.sh
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=inherit
```

That way `systemctl` will "see" that the process is running. The default `KillSignal=` is SIGTERM. So `systemctl stop` will send `SIGTERM` to your bash process, which in turn will make buash execute `shutdown` part. The `TimeoutStopSec=` configures how long to wait for the sript to shutdown.

Comment: PERFECT! Works flawlessly. Thank You Sir.
This is HOW one should answer on StackOverflow - with knowledge, skill, to the point, and helpful.

p.s.
understand all that now, except...
```ifconfig # ??```

what do the # and ?? do please?

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like a good idea to start VPN as a service. It is possible indeed but the service is supposed to start on system boot, so you have to cope with dependency on network etc.

Since your scripts work OK in standalone mode, I would suggest to use them as up/down hooks for a main network interface (see e.g. [Run script when eth0 UP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38523734/run-script-when-eth0-up)).

P.S. In this line

```
while grep ppp0 /proc/net/dev < /dev/null; do
```

you probably wanted to say

```
while grep ppp0 /proc/net/dev > /dev/null; do
```

or

```
while grep -q ppp0 /proc/net/dev; do
```