# How to set systemd to be sure that it stops my application on server shutdown/reboot

Tags: linux, systemd

I would like to setup systemd to start my application when my server is starting up and terminate my application cleanly when th eserver is shutting down.

That's my config. file:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Application
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/my_app start
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/my_app reload
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/my_app stop
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=mixed

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I think that i missed something, because when i reboot my server there's no log about shutting down the application.

log after reboot:

```
# journalctl -u my_app.service
...
-- Reboot --
nov. 24 10:58:51 localhost systemd[1]: Starting My App...
nov. 24 10:58:51 localhost my_app[3173]: ############################################
nov. 24 10:58:51 localhost my_app[3173]: My App start at 2020-11-24 10:58:51
nov. 24 10:58:51 localhost my_app[3173]: ############################################
nov. 24 10:58:51 localhost my_app[3173]: Starting My App
nov. 24 10:58:51 localhost my_app[3173]: debut=Tue Nov 24 10:58:51 CET 2020
nov. 24 10:58:51 localhost my_app[3173]: Tue Nov 24 10:58:51 CET 2020
nov. 24 10:58:51 localhost my_app[3173]: Starting my_app...                             Saving PID 3185  to  /var/run/my_app.pid
nov. 24 10:58:51 localhost my_app[3173]: Ok
nov. 24 10:58:51 localhost my_app[3173]: lock file created
nov. 24 10:58:51 localhost systemd[1]: Started My App.
```

but with a shutdown everything looks good, i can see `nov. 24 13:47:27 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping My App...`

log after shutdown and server start:

```
# journalctl -u my_app.service
...
-- Reboot --
...skipping...
nov. 24 13:43:45 localhost my_app[3138]: Tue Nov 24 13:43:45 CET 2020
nov. 24 13:43:45 localhost my_app[3138]: Starting my_app...                             Saving PID 3151  to  /var/run/my_app.pid
nov. 24 13:43:45 localhost my_app[3138]: Ok
nov. 24 13:43:45 localhost systemd[1]: Started My App.
nov. 24 13:43:45 localhost my_app[3138]: lock file created
nov. 24 13:47:27 localhost systemd[1]: Stopping My App...
nov. 24 13:47:27 localhost my_app[3622]: ############################################
nov. 24 13:47:27 localhost my_app[3622]: My App stop at 2020-11-24 13:47:27
nov. 24 13:47:27 localhost my_app[3622]: ############################################
nov. 24 13:47:27 localhost my_app[3622]: Shutdown My App
nov. 24 13:47:27 localhost my_app[3622]: debut=Tue Nov 24 13:47:27 CET 2020
nov. 24 13:47:27 localhost my_app[3622]: Tue Nov 24 13:47:27 CET 2020
nov. 24 13:47:27 localhost my_app[3622]: root      3151     1  0 13:43 ?        00:00:00 ./ucybsmgr -iucybsmgr.ini AE_PROD
nov. 24 13:47:27 localhost my_app[3622]: root      3524  3151  0 13:44 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/my_app/agents/linux/bin/ucxjlx6
nov. 24 13:47:27 localhost my_app[3622]: nfsnobo+  3526  3524  0 13:44 ?        00:00:00 ucxjlx6-listener
nov. 24 13:47:27 localhost my_app[3622]: root      3649  3644  0 13:47 ?        00:00:00 grep uc
nov. 24 13:47:27 localhost my_app[3622]: Stopping my_app                                3151
nov. 24 13:47:27 localhost my_app[3622]: Ok
nov. 24 13:47:27 localhost my_app[3622]: lock file removed
nov. 24 13:47:27 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped My App.
```

That's why i have some doubt on my config, so if someone can tell me if i'm wrong or not ?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64920825/my-systemd-unit-file-and-bash-scripts-not-working-for-interface-ppp0-checks/64933371#64933371

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [@kamilcuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk) for the link i made some changes my final configuration file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Application
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/my_app start
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/my_app reload
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/my_app stop
TimeoutStopSec=10
# KillMode=mixed

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've disable and remove all links in `/etc/systemd/` before re enable it, so everything looks good on shutdown and reboot.